# Python XHR Request Formatting

Tags: python, ajax

I'm trying to get info from a website using AJAX. When I use the REST plugin for chrome I can send the request and receive the answer required. I want to write a python script but I am stuck as to how to write the request in the correct format. Currently I am getting an unauthorized page response, which I believe is due to not sending it using XHR?

Code:

```
import json
import requests

payload = {"stores":"3650","products":{"31445761":[{"sku":"6000197536050","upc":["4549659075"]}]},"origin":"pip","csrfToken":"d707af2ed8b79a78a669b38dff593c909f6b6262-1507764346644-ebc72845dfa30431a8f7b1c4"}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get("https://www.walmart.ca")
    r = session.post('https://www.walmart.ca/ws/en/products/availability', data=json.dumps(payload),
                 headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"})

    print(r.content)
```

When I am in REST Chrome extension I type:

```
stores=["3650"]&products={"31445761":[{"sku":"6000197536050","upc":["4549659075"]}]}&origin=pip&csrfToken=d707af2ed8b79a78a669b38dff593c909f6b6262-1507764346644-ebc72845dfa30431a8f7b1c4
```

which gives me the desired result.

Desired output:

```
{
31445761: {
"online": [
  {
"maxRegularPrice": 0,
"minRegularPrice": 0,
"mapPrice": 0,
"minCurrentPrice": 99.96,
"maxCurrentPrice": 99.96,
"inventory": 0,
"sku": "6000197536050",
"clearance": false,
"offerId": "6000197536050",
"limited": false,
"reducedPrice": false,
"offerType": "1P",
"limitedStock": false,
"sellerId": "0",
"rollback": false,
"date": "",
"status": "OutOfStock",
"eligible": false,
"sellerName": "Walmart",
"asAdvertised": false
}
],
"stores": [
  {
"minRegularPrice": 0,
"maxRegularPrice": 0,
"minCurrentPrice": 99.96,
"maxCurrentPrice": 99.96,
"inventory": 0,
"sku": "6000197536050",
"clearance": false,
"limited": false,
"limitedStock": false,
"rollback": false,
"date": "",
"status": "OutOfStock",
"storeNumber": "3650",
"eligible": false,
"asAdvertised": false
}
],
"onlineSummary": {
"status": "OutOfStock",
"date": "",
"eligible": false,
"clearance": false,
"rollback": false,
"asAdvertised": false,
"limited": false,
"limitedStock": false,
"minRegularPrice": 0,
"maxRegularPrice": 0,
"minCurrentPrice": 99.96,
"maxCurrentPrice": 99.96
},
"storeSummary": {
"status": "OutOfStock",
"date": "",
"eligible": false,
"clearance": false,
"rollback": false,
"asAdvertised": false,
"limited": false,
"limitedStock": false,
"minRegularPrice": 0,
"maxRegularPrice": 0,
"minCurrentPrice": 99.96,
"maxCurrentPrice": 99.96
}
}
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing a header :

```
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Updated code :

```
import json
import requests

payload = {"stores":"3650","products":{"31445761":[{"sku":"6000197536050","upc":["4549659075"]}]},"origin":"pip","csrfToken":"d707af2ed8b79a78a669b38dff593c909f6b6262-1507764346644-ebc72845dfa30431a8f7b1c4"}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get("https://www.walmart.ca")
    r = session.post('https://www.walmart.ca/ws/en/products/availability', data=json.dumps(payload),
                 headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

    print(r.content)
```

Also, usually the CSRF token changes.
So you should retrieve HTML, get the CSRF token, and then do your XHR POST request.

I would recommend beautifulsoup to find the CSRF token in the HTML.

Comment: I am getting the following when running your revised: 'code:b'{"status":400,"errorCode":1002,"fail":"Could not get online pricing and availability information","errors":[{"errorCode":0,"message":"products: json input missing","constraints":{},"errorcode":0}' ....

Comment: Also, I will automate the token and store numbers once I can get the request working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This error is due to the fact that you aren't sending the good CSRF token IMHO.
You know the CSRF token is a security measure, if you don't send the good one, your request will always fail.

Comment: The token is correct as it works when I use the Chrome extension REST. How do I know that this is using XRF? If I don't use XRF in the extension then I get this exact same unauthorized message.......